# OR and IF function for multiple values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to use the "OR" function in an "IF" function to check a condition on multiple cells.

My formula looks like this `=IF((OR(I5,N5,J5,O5)>7),"Greater than 7 MPa",IF((OR(I5,N5,J5,O5)<4),"Less than 4 MPa",""))`

It is always giving result "Greater than 7" despite of values less than 7 in cells.

I have attached screenshot for the same.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: OR() needs each test like so OR(I5>7,N5>7,J5>7,O5>7)

Comment: or you could use =IF(MIN(I5,N5,J5,O5)>7)

Comment: @user3598756 it should be MAX not MIN if any of the values is greater than 7 or MIN if all the values should be greater than 7, but that means the formula should be an AND not an OR

Comment: @wrbp, yes it should be MAX instead of MIN

Comment: People say "a > 1 or 2". Computers only understand "a>1 or a>2". Stupid machines! :-) :-) :-)

Answer (score 2):

In their current format your `OR` functions are going to return `TRUE` any time a non-zero value is entered in any of the cells being checked.

I suggest the following change: `=IF(OR(I5>7,N5>7,J5>7,O5>7),"Greater than 7 MPa",IF(OR(I5<4,N5<4,J5<4,O5<4),"Less than 4 MPa",""))`